# How to know when iOS app becomes responsive / Hang time

Tags: ios, performance, grand-central-dispatch, responsiveness

Is there a way to know when an iOS app becomes responsive to user interaction? For example, a user taps a button and the app performs work, this work may dispatch other work asynchronously to the main thread. In hopes of using it as a performance metric, I want to know the precise moment at which the app is again able to process touch events in a responsive manner. With this I would want data like "On average, the app becomes responsive 55ms after a user interaction".

Currently, immediately after a user interaction, I watch the main queue and have a heuristic for submitting samples to it in order to estimate responsiveness based on the main queue's responsiveness, with the assumption that the main queue's responsiveness directly correlates with the apps' responsiveness. The sampling only occurs until the queue is again consistently responsive for some time again (ex. 100ms). Is there any downside to this method? Is there any other method I could/should be using to do this?

Using MetricKit to watch for Hang Time is not an option as I cannot those results to a specific interaction (i.e. knowing how different interactions affect hang time).

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> For example, a user taps a button and the app performs work. I want to know the precise moment at which the app is again able to process touch events in a responsive manner.

The main thread should *never* be blocked. It should *always* be responsive. (You can disable the UI if your app requires that, but never block the main thread, regardless.)

So, with that in mind, if you are starting some process that takes a little time, you should:

1. If you want the app to let the user know that a time consuming process is about to start, add that chrome to the UI (e.g. `UIActivityIndicatorView`, aka a “spinner”, or whatever);
2. Start that task, asynchronously, on a background queue (so that it does not block the main thread);
3. Give that task a “completion handler” closure that it will call when the background work is done;
4. In that completion handler, the caller can supply the code to remove any chrome added in the first step, above.

In short, rather than worrying about “how does the app know when the main thread is free again”, you should focus on eliminating anything that would ever block the main thread in the first place. See [Understand and eliminate hangs from your app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10258).

Comment: Thanks for the response. And sorry, should have been clearer in my question. The amount of work performed is dynamic and server-driven. I need this as a performance metric. This specific problem is not about reducing the amount of work, but measuring it, keeping into account that it may contain work dispatched asynchronously like delegates, so it isn't simply a matter of measuring start and end.

Comment: Thanks for the comment: My point is that you can measure the elapsed time a variety of ways, but the idea of “in order to estimate responsiveness based on the main queue's responsiveness” makes no sense when the main queue is always responsive. Now if you didn't mean “main queue” and instead meant “UI” (because you disable UI before initiating the async process and re-enable the UI when done), that's another matter. But the main queue should always be responsive. If not, one should first just fix that first.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I agree the main queue should always be responsive. That's precisely why I sample it to measure unresponsiveness time. The assumption is that after a user interaction, the app becomes busy in order to process work. What I want to answer is how long does this work last and the app is able to process events in a responsive manner again. When the queue becomes responsive, I log the time, and stop sampling it, so this measurement is only done when I submit work as a result of a user interaction.